# Fixing Overlapping Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one div inside a div:

```
<div id="opacnavigation" class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">        
    <div id="opacnavigation-btn" class="btn-group">              

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ">
            <i class="icon-home"></i>
            Home                    
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">        
            <i class="icon-comment"></i>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                About the Library                                         
            </a>            

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Library Hours</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Board of Visitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Department and Staff</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Direction Maps</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Equipment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Floor Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Information and Policies</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Mission and Vision</a></li>
           </ul>    
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success ">
            <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>   
            Help
        </button>                                       
    </div> 
</div>
```

First Div:

[image]

Second Div:

[image]

But why does the inner div overlaps the first one?The Second Div must be inside my first div.Here is my CSS Code:

```
#opacnavigation{
    background-color: #0C6A13;
    margin: 0;
    border-top:2px solid;
    border-bottom:2px solid;   
}

#opacnavigation-btn{
    background-color: #0C6A13;         
    margin-left: 15px;                 
    width: 100%;   
} 

.btn-group > .btn, 
.btn-group > .btn-group, 
.btn-group > .btn-group > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    max-width: 92%;
    width: 92%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.btn-group .btn + .btn,
.btn-group .btn + .btn-group,
.btn-group .btn-group + .btn,
.btn-group .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.btn-group > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;   
}

.btn-group > .btn:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;              
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'overlap' but the reason it's offset is the `margin-left: 15px;` on `#opacnavigation-btn`, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: and you don't need to specify the width to `100%` for a block element, because it will fill the remaining width of it's parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be because of the `margin-left: 15px;` given to the `#opacnavigation-btn`.

The calculated offset of this div will be the addition of its parent div's width and the margin given.

A solution to this is give margin to the child div.

Comment: --> is there anyway I could put margin without affecting it's parent's div width?

Comment: Don't specify width to the `margin-left` div. By default it will take `width` 100% if it is `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

m not sure exactly what solution u r looking for...
but have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h88o9kwb/1/) according to my understanding.. please improvise on that...

remove  `width:100%`  on  `#opacnavigation-btn`,
replace margin by padding